# Gulp cli is not installing, gulp cli installation problems

Tags: wordpress, gulp, wordpress-theming, gulp-sass

i am trying gulp cli ever this error is apper

```
gulp : The term 'gulp' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the 
spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ gulp
+ ~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (gulp:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3UmkV.png)

how to resoleve this error